# How to do something on swipe page in PageView?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to do something when page is swiping in PageView? The is nothing that could help in `controller` property - it has `keepPage` and `viewPortFraction` also.

```
  final _controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
  ...
  body: PageView(
    controller: _controller,
    children: const [
      Statistic(type: StatType.day),
      Statistic(type: StatType.total),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: yeah obviously. use PageView.builder instead & add a listener to Controller.pageOffset then what u wanna do

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

`onPageChanged` is called in the PageView when you have swiped it halfway.

Or you can also add a listener:

```
_controller = PageController()..addListener(_listener);

_listener() {
   // LOGIC HERE
    });
```